# Make Button in ListBox available without having to select the item before

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, listboxitem

I have a ListBox with a DataTemplate. In the DataTemplate is a button (an image) and a label (description). The button is only clickable when the item from the listbox is previously selected. It is possible to click on the button also without selecting the listbox item previously?
This would work with an ItemControl, but I have some style that works only on a ListBox. I use MVVM.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to delete this in my code:

```
if (item == SelectedItem)
{
 ...
}
```